# Crashing when using free in the incorrect way

Tags: c, string, malloc, realloc, double-pointer

```
typedef char* DString;
DString dstring_initialize(const char* str);
int dstring_concatenate(DString* destination, DString source);
void dstring_delete(DString* stringToDelete);

int main(void)
{
    DString str1, str2;

    str1 = dstring_initialize("hello ");
    str2 = dstring_initialize("world");
    dstring_concatenate(&str1, str2);
    dstring_delete(&str1);
    dstring_delete(&str2);

}

DString dstring_initialize(const char* str)
{
    char* res = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
    if (res != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(res, str);
    }
    return res;
}

int dstring_concatenate(DString* destination, DString source)
{
    DString newstr = realloc(*destination, ((strlen(*destination)+1)+ strlen((&source)+1))* sizeof *source);
    if(newstr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error");
    }
    strcat(newstr, source);
    *destination = newstr;

    return 1;
}

void dstring_delete(DString* stringToDelete)
{
    assert(stringToDelete != NULL);
    free(stringToDelete);
    assert(*stringToDelete == NULL);
}
```

I suspect that my allocation is wrong or the freeing of the memory allocated is incorrect because when I debug the code, it gets stuck at the `free(stringToDelete);` part and then crashes. Another thing is I suspect that the `realloc` part is not correct. Any help would be appreciated, and if the question is terrible, feel free to comment so that I can improve my communications skills and further improve the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `realloc`, take a close look here:

```
 strlen((&source)+1))
```

You're passing a `char **` to `strlen`.  What you want is:

```
 strlen(source)+1
```

With the full line being:

```
DString newstr = realloc(*destination, (strlen(*destination) + 1 + 
                                        strlen(source) + 1) * sizeof *source);
```

The problem with the `free` is you're passing in what was allocated.  You're instead passing in the address of a local variable in `main`.  You need to dereference:

```
free(*stringToDelete);
```

Also, freeing memory doesn't set the pointer to NULL, so you should remove the `assert` after the `free`.  Actually you can remove the other assert as well since passing a NULL pointer to `free` is well defined.

Comment: I still get a crash, `Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)` and whenever I debug it codeblock cant move past `free(*stringToDelete);`

Comment: @Darke It runs clean in valgrind for me.  Did you copy the `realloc` line above *exactly*?

Comment: yeah it runs now sry for the stupid comment it was an `; : `problem where I placed the wrong column

Answer (score 2):

so the problem is that you are passing to dstring_delete a variable of type DString*
and you ask it to free it, however if we look at DString* we find that it is char**
but in the other functions like dstring_initialize you allocated res of type char*
**so you are asking the compiler to free something you have never allocated** which causes your code to crash :
here is the new code, check if it works :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef char* DString;
DString dstring_initialize(const char* str);
int dstring_concatenate(DString* destination, DString source);
void dstring_delete(DString stringToDelete);

int main(void)
{
    DString str1, str2;

    str1 = dstring_initialize("hello ");
    str2 = dstring_initialize("world");
    dstring_concatenate(&str1, str2);
    dstring_delete(str1);
    dstring_delete(str2);

}

DString dstring_initialize(const char* str)
{
    char* res = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
    if (res != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(res, str);
    }
    return res;
}

int dstring_concatenate(DString* destination, DString source)
{
    DString newstr = realloc(*destination, ((strlen(*destination)+1)+ strlen((&source)+1))* sizeof *source);
    if(newstr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error");
    }
    strcat(newstr, source);
    *destination = newstr;

    return 1;
}

void dstring_delete(DString stringToDelete)
{
    assert(stringToDelete != NULL);
    free(stringToDelete);
    stringToDelete = NULL;
    assert(stringToDelete == NULL);
}
```

one more thing **free does not assign NULL to the freed pointer**, it becomes junk data, so you need to assign it to NULL before asserting if it's NULL